# Switching logic on Domain Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I'm currently developing an app using ASP.NET MVC3 and Entity Framework 4.1 Code First and also trying to apply DDD little by little since I'm only began learning it.

I have a model of :

```
public class ClassA
{
    public decimal MonthlyRate { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal DailyRate 
    { 
       get { return this.MonthlyRate / 30; }
       private set { }
    }
}
```

Right now, this code works but what if I'll be having a flag (which will be checked by user) on the View triggering for a new computation. Let's say the flag instead of dividing it by 30, monthly rate now will be divided by 5. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface IDivideLogic
{
    int DivideNumber{get;set;}
}

class DivideLogic : IDivideLogic
{
    public DivideLogic()
    {
        DivideNumber = 30;
    }
    public DivideLogic(int divideNumber)
    {
        DivideNumber = divideNumber;
    }
    public int DivideNumber{get;set;}
}

public class ClassA
{
    public IDivideLogic DivideLogic {get;set;}
    public decimal MonthlyRate { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal DailyRate 
    { 
       get { return this.MonthlyRate / DivideLogic.DivideNumber; }
       private set { }
    }
}
```

then you can switch this when you want

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA();
obj.DivideLogic  = new DivideLogic(5);
```

This works well for more complicated situations. In your situation it may be too over designed. Hope you get the point

Comment: Thanks. I got your point but what if the the value is fixed? and the flag is just telling the Domain that to use the other value instead of the original one?

Comment: You can create a couple of DivideLogic object's with different predefined values, and then just set those objects to DivideLogic property

Comment: ok got it. Is this method doesn't validate DDD? I'm not currently sure since I'm still learning it but based from the article I read, Domain Models should have behaviors/computations/logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a strategy pattern for this. You could use various implementations of your division logic. Assuming you want to anticipate further change this would be a good way to solve this problem. This way you abstract the division logic from the other logic making it easy to implement different implementations of the division logic.

Comment: I was thinking to use that too, should I have a base class then? having the common computation and override it on it's derived class? But then, how should I persist it on the db?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the value as a property and assign it from UI.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public decimal MonthlyRate { get; set; }
    public int YourProperty {get; set;}

    public ClassA(int yourProperty)
    {
        YourProperty = yourProperty;
    }

    public virtual decimal DailyRate 
    { 
       get { return this.MonthlyRate / YourProperty; }
       private set { }
    }
}
```